# Textgeometry not visible in three.js scene

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've added a boxgeometry in the scene on which I want to add text to verify the side of the cube. but, I'm not able to add textgeometry in the scene.

this is my code: -

```
const loader = new FontLoader();
loader.load( 'fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json',
function ( font ) { const geometry = new TextGeometry( 'Hello three.js!', { font: font, size: 80,                                                                                                                                                         height: 5, curveSegments: 12, bevelEnabled: true, bevelThickness: 10, bevelSize: 8, bevelOffset: 0, bevelSegments: 5 } ); } );
```

I've stored the helvetiker_regular.typeface.json file in the fonts folder but was not been able to get the path. Any suggestion or any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please demonstrate what you are doing with a live example: https://jsfiddle.net/g3atw6k5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL may not work directly to load the Json file imports. first you'll have to add the file path in the imports section and then add the component name over there

```
       var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
       var font = loader.parse(helveticaRegular); 
       var textGeometry = new THREE.TextGeometry( 'Hello three.js!', 
       {font: font,
        size: 1,
        height: 0.1, 
        curveSegments: 20 } );
       var textMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 
       0xF00000 } ); 
       var textMesh = new THREE.Mesh( textGeometry, textMaterial ); 
       this.scene.add(textMesh);
```

I have used the helveticaRegular Font file .you can add your own font by downloading TTF file and then converting in to Json :https://gero3.github.io/facetype.js/